# Validation Errors of reduxForm can't be cleared?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using reduxForm 6.x, and defines a form with fields: `list[0], list[0].a, list[1], list[1].a, ...`.
My submitError structure would look like:

```
{
   list: [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]
}
```

After user give correct input to each field of `list`, the error structure becomes:

```
{
  list: [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

The problem is, redux-form will consider empty object as an error, so `list[0]` field will have error forever. For now, I can only avoid this problem by not defining `list[0]` field, and only defines `list[0].a` field.

Is this behavior the intention of redux-form, or it's a bug?